# Compute loss for for multi-class classification when using cross validation

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, cross-validation, mnist

I am training my neural network on the MNIST data set with handwritten digits. I use PyTorch and wondered what's the right way to compute the loss when using cross validation (Kfold) with 5 folds? I want to plot a loss graph which is comparing train and test loss.

I am using cross-entropy loss as the loss function. Should I take the average of the loss for each epoch in each fold? Such that if I am using 5 epochs, the loss graph consists of 5 datapoints, where the first point corresponds to the average loss for the first epoch of all 5 folds?

I also use a batch-size of 128. At first the loss is around 1,61 and at the end it's around around 1,47. The model has a accuracy of 97.7%, is this little decrease in loss strange?

Comment: What are you cross validating? Hyperparameter settings?

Comment: Cross validates through the pictures(x_train) which is flattened and the belonging labels (y_train). Using Adam as optimizer, lr = 0.00095, one hidden linear layer with 597 hidden neurons. @jchaykow